# How to calculate first derivative of time series

Tags: r, derivative

I would calculate the first derivative (dpH/dtime) of time series using two variables, `time` and `pH`.

Are there any kind of functions to do this in R or should I compute an extra function to do this?

Comment: `diff.ts` comes to mind.

Comment: or more crudely `diff(pH)/diff(time)`; it depends also whether you want to do some kind of smoothing.

Comment: I used the function diff, e.g. derivative <-diff(pH)/diff(time) but I get other values in comparison with the manual calculation with excel. In excel I made it so: (pH2-pH1)/(time2-time1). Why?

Comment: almost impossible to say without a reproducible example ( http://tinyurl.com/reproducible-000 ).  Assuming that `pH1` is a lagged version of `pH2` and the same for `time1`/`time2`, your calculations *should* give the same result ...

Comment: you are right, I had a export problem in R. In excel the time difference was 0.16667 but I export the time serie only with one decimal number. Sorry for the mistake.

Comment: I think either we should close this question, or you should post a worked example showing what you did that worked (i.e., really just an example of `diff(pH)/diff(time)` ...)

Answer (score 19):

Assuming `pH` and `time` are plain vectors try this:

```
library(pspline)
predict(sm.spline(time, pH), time, 1)
```

Answer (score 12):

You might want to start with `stats::deriv`  or `diff.ts` as Matt L suggested.  Just keep in mind what a professor of mine used to tell all his students:  numeric differentiation is known as "error multiplier."

EDIT:
To clarify -- what he was warning about was that any noise in your data can throw the derivative estimate way off.  It's been said that integration is a low-pass filter and differentiation is a high-pass filter.
So, the important thing is to do some smoothing on your data before calculating a derivative. Hence Gabor's excellent suggestion to use `predict.spline` .  But keep in mind that modifying the spline parameters will smooth your data to different levels, so always look at the results to make sure you removed apparent noise but not desired features.

Comment: Could you add a line or two to explain that "numeric differentiation aka error multiplier"? Really curious.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a link to "Numerical Differentiation".

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_differentiation

Here's a link describing a method based on Taylor Series Expansions:

http://ocw.usu.edu/civil_and_environmental_engineering/numerical_methods_in_civil_engineering/ODEsMatlab.pdf

Comment: this is useful information but not, I think, relevant to the OP's question (which is about finding the derivative of time series data, not about finding/approximating the derivative of an explicitly defined function ...)

Comment: @BenBolker - You're right.   `numDeriv` is not the right package.   I can't find the right package at the moment (maybe I'm remembering a package from a different language?), but the technique is just standard Taylor Series methods.   I'll replace the `numDeriv` link.